# How to I pass a symbol to an instance's attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I pass a symbol argument to an instance's attribute?

```
<%= image_input_and_display(f, :footer, '1140 x 104 pixels') %>

def image_input_and_display(f, symbol, hint)
  f.input symbol, hint: hint
  if @user.symbol.exists?
    ...
  end
end
```

I'm trying to get the function to run, in this case, `if @user.footer.exists?`. Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you want to execute a method when you know it's name so `Object#send` is what you want. `send` runs a method by it's name.

```
@user.send(symbol).exists?
```

Just be warned, this gives access to all methods on that object.  What would this do?

```
image_input_and_display(f, :destroy, '1140 x 104 pixels')
```

The answer? Something very bad. It looks as if it's just accessing a property, but it could be doing something you didn't expect under the hood. Just be careful :)

Comment: Good advice too. It is just accessing a property, but that's really good to note.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand exactly what you are asking, but it sounds like a dynamic method call.  [Object implements send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-send).  You can call `@user.send(symbol)`.